# How to Stop Procdump Programmatically

Tags: windows, automation, crash, dump, procdump

I'm running procdump on a server to try and debug a crash. The crash only happens at night (don't ask me why :P). I would like to run procdump overnight and then stop it in the morning. I know that if you run it from the command line you can hit ctrl+c and procdump will exit and leave your process intact.

I want to do this from a scrip, is that possible? I can start procdump just fine but I can't figure out how to stop it. When I print the help it has the following line:

> Automated Termination:
>      Setting an event with the name "procdump-" is the same as typing Ctrl+C to gracefully terminate ProcDump.

I don't understand this though, how do I set an event? Googling hasn't helped (though maybe I'm asking the wrong question?).

I know this is probably a very silly question but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
procdump -u
```

will do the job nicely.